# Recyclerview is blank when getting data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am getting data from Firebase and displaying it in a recyclerview. When I run it, nothing shows up and I don't get any errors. The debugger shows that i am retrieving all the data correctly, but it shows the arraylist keeps returning a size of zero.

Here is my database structure:

```
{
 "Classes" : {
   "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi" : {
  "Students" : {
    "-LiId4URjJ8SWLAP4f4i" : "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22",
    "-LiIeT5t1T7JpcUee_MJ" : "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22"
  },
  "class_info" : {
    "date_clasname" : "mm",
    "room_number" : "jjhh",
    "subject" : "Science",
    "teacher" : "mm",
    "uid" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
  }
}
  },
   "Users" : {
    "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22" : {
    "Classes" : {
    "-LiIeT5slTjC0B3lEqNJ" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
    "-LiIeT5slTjC0B3lEqNJ" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
  },
    "User_info" : {
    "email" : "samuelford48@gmail.com",
    "grade" : "12",
    "name" : "Samuel"
  }
```

Here is the code for my activity:

```
public class home_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button button;
//DatabaseReference dref;
//ListView listview2;
//ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private List<Listdata> list;
private RecyclerView recyclerview;
public home_fragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    //FirebaseUser fbUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //if(fbUser == null) { Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    // startActivity(intent);}

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Users")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Classes");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            list = new ArrayList<>();
                String class_id = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                myRef = database.getReference("Classes").child(class_id).child("class_info");
            // StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Class_model new_class = dataSnapshot.getValue(Class_model.class);
                        assert new_class != null;
                        String nameofclass = new_class.getDate_clasname();
                        String teacherofclass = new_class.getTeacher();
                        String roomnumberofclass = new_class.getRoom_number();
                        String class_key = new_class.getUid();
                        Listdata listdata = new Listdata(nameofclass, teacherofclass, roomnumberofclass, class_key);
                        //String name = userdetails.getName();
                        //String email = userdetails.getEmail();
                        //String address = userdetails.getAddress();
                        listdata.setDate_class(nameofclass);
                        listdata.setTeacher(teacherofclass);
                        listdata.setRnumber(roomnumberofclass);
                    list.add(listdata);
                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            });

            RecyclerviewAdapter2 recycler = new RecyclerviewAdapter2(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

                                });
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    signout();



    //startActivity(new Intent(home_fragment.this, LoginActivity.class));

}
public void signout(){
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


   }
 }
```

First, the activity is getting the id's of the classes, which are stored under the user's classes, then it gets the class info and displays it in the recyclerview.
Here is the code for my adapter(there shouldn't be a problem here):

```
public class RecyclerviewAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter2.MyHolder>{

List<Listdata> listdata;

public RecyclerviewAdapter2(List<Listdata> listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
}

@Override
public RecyclerviewAdapter2.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_class_model,parent,false);

    RecyclerviewAdapter2.MyHolder myHolder = new RecyclerviewAdapter2.MyHolder(view);
    return myHolder;
}


public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerviewAdapter2.MyHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Listdata data = listdata.get(position);
    holder.vdate_class.setText(data.getDate_class());
    holder.vteacher.setText(data.getTeacher());
    holder.vrnumber.setText(data.getRnumber());
    //System.out.println(data.getDate_class2());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( final View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Add_class_to_user.class);
            intent.putExtra("date_class", listdata.get(position).getDate_class());
            intent.putExtra("teacher", listdata.get(position).getTeacher());
            intent.putExtra("room_number", listdata.get(position).getRnumber());
            intent.putExtra("post_key", listdata.get(position).getUid());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listdata.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView vdate_class , vteacher,vrnumber;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vdate_class = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_class_name);
        vteacher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher);
        vrnumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_number);

    }
   }

}
```

Thank you and let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `ADAPTER_NAME.notifyDataSetChanged()` after data is added to the list to reflect the changes in the RecyclerView. Don't forget to replace `ADAPTER_NAME` with the actual adapter name.

Comment: You should do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you add items to list

Answer (score -2):

You are calling this logic

```
 database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Users")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Classes");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            list = new ArrayList<>();
                String class_id = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                myRef = database.getReference("Classes").child(class_id).child("class_info");
            // StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Class_model new_class = dataSnapshot.getValue(Class_model.class);
                        assert new_class != null;
                        String nameofclass = new_class.getDate_clasname();
                        String teacherofclass = new_class.getTeacher();
                        String roomnumberofclass = new_class.getRoom_number();
                        String class_key = new_class.getUid();
                        Listdata listdata = new Listdata(nameofclass, teacherofclass, roomnumberofclass, class_key);
                        //String name = userdetails.getName();
                        //String email = userdetails.getEmail();
                        //String address = userdetails.getAddress();
                        listdata.setDate_class(nameofclass);
                        listdata.setTeacher(teacherofclass);
                        listdata.setRnumber(roomnumberofclass);
                    list.add(listdata);
                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            });

            RecyclerviewAdapter2 recycler = new RecyclerviewAdapter2(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

                                });
```

Inside your `onCreateView()` method, since this is a Fragment, inside `onCreateView()` you only should have the view initialization, then in `onViewCreated()` or `onActivityCreated()` you should have the above code.

I think the problem comes because after you instantiate your views, you call an asynchronous process (getting data from firebase) to fill your `RecyclerView`, but the `RecyclerView` view is not reached.

Comment: can you show me how to do it? I tried it and I am not sure i did it correctly, but it didn't work

Comment: just override onViewCreated() like you do with onCreateView()